# Scoping Issues pointing at wrong 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, this

I have been smashing my head against a wall for a few days now when trying to solve an issue involving `this`. When I call `this.model` on `initialize`, it returns contact information correctly, though as soon as I edit information and click the save button, `this.model` comes up `undefined`. After a little searching and a lot of console logs it seems that `this` is taking after the button on click. Ideally, the save button will compare previous values with updated values and then update the model before pushing it to the database. Here is what my messy `initialize` currently looks like:

```js
initialize: function(contact) {
  this.listenTo(App.Emitter, 'contacts:edit', this.render);
  this.template = window['JST']['editContact'];
  this.collection = App.Contacts2;

  if (contact.model) {
    console.log('INITIALIZE CONTACT HAS A MODEL', contact) // shows correct data
  }

  $('.save').on('click', this.save.bind(this))
  // this.$('.save').on('click', (contact)=> this.save(contact)) <--- also tried with no success

}
```

Once we get to the `save` function however, everything goes bananas. On click, I am getting a `console.log` showing `this` of the button property and not the passed information:

```js
save: function(contact) {
  console.log('SAVE FUNCTION START: ', contact, this) //contact= button's 'this', this= object with view's 'this' but no contact information

  if (contact.model) {
    this.yay = contact.model
    console.log('save function', this.yay) // doesn't show up :(
  }

  console.log('secondary model', this.yay) // undefined
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why `this` is so stubborn? I just need the contact data to make it to the save function.

Comment: `this.$('.save')` looks really odd. Is there really a "$" property on your objects?

Comment: sorry, must be a typo on that one. I am using jQuery to select the button class, 'save'

Comment: You stated "When I call this.model on initialize, it returns contact information", but in the code I never see a reference to "this.model".  I see contact.model, but I don't see how contact would be passed to the save onclick function (I think that is an event argument passed in unless I am missing something).  

Did you try saving the contact as this.model and using that inside the save function?

Comment: @Pointy there is a [`$` property on Backbone views](https://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar), it is a scoped jQuery object cached at view creation to improve DOM manipulations.

Comment: You can manage events on a View with the [`events` hash](https://backbonejs.org/#View-events), e.g. `"click .save": "save"`

Comment: @DDupont, I stripped out some of the code in the save function for the sake of keeping the code snips smaller, though you are correct, the model saving function was not listed above. I was able to track my issue down to be related to the initialize function being a little screwy. By placing the bind and listener in the render function, it seems to have cleared up this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @EmileBergeron ah OK, I kind-if figured it was something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I found that my solution was two part:

First, I needed to bind the event in the render function instead of the initialize function.

Secondly, I needed to add a new event listener in the render function instead in the events, though I am not entirely sure why this works.

Here is what the render function looks like with the 2 added lines:

```
    render: function() {

    this.$el.html( this.template() );
    this.editContact();
    $('.saveEdit').on('click', _.bind(this.save, this))
    this.listenTo(App.Emitter, 'save', this.save())
    return this;
},
```

Comment: You really shouldn’t be doing `$('.saveEdit').on('click', _.bind(this.save, this))`, if you use backbone event binding you shouldn’t have context issues

Comment: @TJ can you please give an example of this?

Comment: https://backbonejs.org/#View-events

`events: {
 ‘click .saveEdit’: ‘save’
}`

these create events delegated on the view element for working with dynamically generated elements.